# Check if Remote Server Port is Blocking my IKEv2/IPSec VPN Connections

Tags: networking, vpn, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn, strongswan

I am using StrongSwan on Ubuntu to try to establish a site-to-site VPN connection to a remote IKEv2 IPSec VPN server, but it appears that my connection requests are not reaching the remote server.

Is there anyway for me to use my server to check whether the port that I am trying to connect to is being dropped by the remote server's firewall?

Tried using `telnet <remote-ip> 500` on a VPN server that is known to work, but this command is simply timing out. I do not have access to the remote VPN servers.

Thank you!

**StrongSwan Logs**

```
initiating IKE_SA remoteServer[3] to 2.2.2.2
generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) V ]
sending packet: from 10.150.0.33[500] to 2.2.2.2[500] (1256 bytes)
retransmit 1 of request with message ID 0
sending packet: from 10.150.0.33[500] to 2.2.2.2[500] (1256 bytes)
retransmit 2 of request with message ID 0
sending packet: from 10.150.0.33[500] to 2.2.2.2[500] (1256 bytes)
retransmit 3 of request with message ID 0
sending packet: from 10.150.0.33[500] to 2.2.2.2[500] (1256 bytes)
retransmit 4 of request with message ID 0
sending packet: from 10.150.0.33[500] to 2.2.2.2[500] (1256 bytes)
retransmit 5 of request with message ID 0
sending packet: from 10.150.0.33[500] to 2.2.2.2[500] (1256 bytes)
giving up after 5 retransmits
establishing IKE_SA failed, peer not responding
establishing connection 'remoteServer' failed
```

**sudo tcpdump udp port 500** (captured on client)

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ens4, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
13:14:25.475539 IP my-server.us-east4-c.c.foo-bar-142406.internal.isakmp > 2.2.2.2.isakmp: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]
13:14:29.475878 IP my-server.us-east4-c.c.foo-bar-142406.internal.isakmp > 2.2.2.2.isakmp: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]
13:14:36.676279 IP my-server.us-east4-c.c.foo-bar-142406.internal.isakmp > 2.2.2.2.isakmp: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]
13:14:49.636657 IP my-server.us-east4-c.c.foo-bar-142406.internal.isakmp > 2.2.2.2.isakmp: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]
13:15:12.965064 IP my-server.us-east4-c.c.foo-bar-142406.internal.isakmp > 2.2.2.2.isakmp: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]
13:15:54.955428 IP my-server.us-east4-c.c.foo-bar-142406.internal.isakmp > 2.2.2.2.isakmp: isakmp: parent_sa ikev2_init[I]
```

Comment: Probably a NAT problem. Check for the existence of NAT at both ends. Eliminate NAT if possible, otherwise configure the NAT device to pass the traffic.

Comment: Was that capture on the client or the server? Anything in the server log? The message is quite large, what DH group did you configure? Does it work with other DH groups?

Answer (score 0):

To be sure whether your traffic reaches the remote VPN server you have to ask the administrator of that server.

But using tcpdump you can look for ICMP traffic that indicates that the destination for your traffic is unreachable. You would check this for instance like this:

```
sudo tcpdump -w vpn.pcap 'host 2.2.2.2 or icmp[0] = 3'
```

This will possibly catch more ICMP traffic than you want.

Lastly you can check the IKE phase 1 parameters that your server sends by inspecting *vpn.pcap* with Wireshark. The first IKE message is always unencrypted and Wireshark has decent packet dissectors for it.

Some VPN servers don't respond at all if the initial IKE_SA_INIT request does not contain the right parameters.

Regarding NAT, IKEv2 can handle this when the appropriate options are set.